# How to fix "No module named 'nmap'"

Tags: python, import, nmap

```
import nmap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap'
```

the above is the result when trying to run the code after importing nmap. (I have installed python-nmap using pip in cmd)

Comment: What IDE do you use? Do you have your module in your path?

Comment: You should check your python environment variables.

Comment: im using visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1:
Uninstall the package using:

```
pip3 uninstall python-nmap
```

STEP 2:
Install the package:

```
pip3 install --user python-nmap
```

Comment: hmm. tried this but doesnt work. import nmap works on pycharm but not on visual studio 2019. i think my visual studio IDE does not know where to look for the libraries. pre installed libraries like socket works fine

Answer (score 0):

i found out the issue. when i chose a python env eg- python 3.8 32bit from the IDE, i chose a custom version thats why the imports dont work. when i chose the default env it worked. anyways thank for the help. there is nothing wrong with the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get it working:

1. Install the latest version of Python3 (3.9.6) https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-396/
2. On your terminal:

   ```
   pip3 install python-nmap
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to get things to work:

1. On your terminal, switch to root privilege:
   `su - root`
2. Then, install python-nmap module:
   `pip3 install python-nmap`

Reference: `https://github.com/securipy/nmap-scan/issues/26`

Comment: Why do you need to switch to superuser if you are using `sudo`?

Comment: @shhh Right, you don't have to use the sudo command and thanks for pointing that out. For some reason, I needed to switch to root user for pip3 install python-nmap to work.